# DocsList getSize() always returns zero

Tags: google-apps-script

```
Logger.log(DocsList.getRootFolder().getFolders()[0].getSize()); //returns zero
Logger.log(DocsList.getRootFolder().getFiles()[0].getSize()); //returns zero
```

Any tips???

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is normal behavior ... a Google folder has no size... and the first file you get is probably a Google document (or spreadsheet) which has no size either (meaning it takes no space, only 'foreign files' take space in your drive storage).

This is clearly explained in the [DRIVE UI](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2736257&p=storage_overview) when they tell you that you have a free 5 GB storage and how this is to be considered

Answer (score 0):

Folder.getSize () is not a documented method. So, its hard to say what is expected as output. 
If you are looking to get the number of folders in the root folder, use

```
Logger.log(DocsList.getRootFolder().getFolders().length);
```